title page format, author field with setbeamertemplate and general outline
I'm cleaning up my title page and was working on the author filed as per this post. Unfortunately, I cannot attain exactly what I needed and changed some parts to match the intended results; however, I think I messed up somewhere since my Candidate header is not centered in the column... is there a way to do so. Below a MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme[width=0cm,height=.65in]{sidebar}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\definecolor{bground}{HTML}{005EB8}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=anti-flashwhite,bg=bground}

\setbeamertemplate{author}{%
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec={X[halign=c,valign=m]X[halign=c,valign=m]},
    row{1}={font=\centering\bfseries}
  }
  \SetCell[c=2]{}
  Candidate & & Supervisors \\
  Given Name & & Prof. X \\
  Surname & & Prof. Y \\
  \end{tblr}
}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber=1%
        {\begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \fill [color=bground] (0,0.668\paperheight) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    \fi%
}

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
\ifnum\c@framenumber>1%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=\beamerheadheight]{example-image-a}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\else%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=-2pt]
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[height=1.25in]{example-image-a}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\fi%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\title[Ph.D. defense]{FIRST LINE \\ SECOND LINE \\ THIRD LINE}
\author{Surname, Given Name}
\institute[]{\centering Ph.D. Program in \\ \dots \\ \rom{36}\textdegree cycle}
\date[\today]{\centering Academic Years yyyy/yyyy – yyyy/yyyy}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=.5in]{example-image-b}}

\setbeamerfont{title}{shape=\bfseries,size=\LARGE}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=anti-flashwhite}
\addtobeamertemplate{title}{\vskip-.3in}{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[left,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\makeatother

\begin{document}

{\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}\begin{frame}[t]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

Also, I'm attempting to have a top-left alignment for the title which seems to not be working correctly after I removed the [default] option from
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[left,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\makeatother

Lastly, I was looking into how to print the same exact image as in the headline for the Test frame, but bigger in the top-right corner of the title page; somehow the code I was using seems to not be working anymore and I'm not really sure why is it...
Apologies for the code but I'm not very experienced and I understand there are better ways to do this; I couldn't figure out how to work at the background level, so in order to change the size of the headline in the title page I had to first suppress it and then add a background canvas, as I was used to. Thanks in advance!

Please don't mix different problems in a single post.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I will ask in a separate post, about the title and the image. Thanks again!

With \SetCell[c=2]{}, the cell will span over two columns. If you want it centred in the first column, remove this.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme[width=0cm,height=.65in]{sidebar}

\usepackage{tabularray}


\setbeamertemplate{author}{%
  \begin{tblr}{
    colspec={X[halign=c,valign=m]X[halign=c,valign=m]X[halign=c,valign=m]},
    row{1}={font=\centering\bfseries}
  }
%  \SetCell[c=2]{}
  Candidate & & Supervisors \\
  Given Name & & Prof. X \\
  Surname & & Prof. Y \\
  \end{tblr}
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother

\title[Ph.D. defense]{FIRST LINE \\ SECOND LINE \\ THIRD LINE}
\author{Surname, Given Name}
\institute[]{\centering Ph.D. Program in \\ \dots \\ \rom{36}\textdegree cycle}
\date[\today]{\centering Academic Years yyyy/yyyy – yyyy/yyyy}
\logo{\includegraphics[height=.5in]{example-image-b}}


\begin{document}

{\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}\begin{frame}[t]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}}

\end{document}



thanks for the clarification. I could see that \SetCell[c=2]{} had a merge effect but didn't know if was correct to remove it. Also, thanks for indicating the way to space apart the two column, that was going to be my next question since with only X[halign=c,valign=m]X[halign=c,valign=m] they appear centered in the frame.
